# How to convert datetime string without timezone to another datetime with timezone in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out how to convert a datetime string to another datetime string with timezone.

Here's the example.

`07/27/2015:06:00 AM` to `20150727060000 -0400`

The default timezone would be EST.

Here's my code so far.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def _to_datetime(air_date, air_time):
    schedule_time = '{}:{}'.format(air_date, air_time)
    return datetime.strptime(schedule_time,'%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p')
```

Comment: I believe it's `%z`.

Comment: But the input doesn't have any timezone. The input doesn't have any timezone and the output I want it with EST timezone.

Comment: Then you need to indicate it in some way. How else is it supposed to determine the time zone from a plain string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `dateutil` to add the `tzinfo` to the `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz

AmericaNewYorkTz = tz.gettz('America/New_York')

def _to_datetime(air_date, air_time):
    schedule_time = '{}:{}'.format(air_date, air_time)
    return datetime.strptime(schedule_time,'%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p').replace(tzinfo=AmericaNewYorkTz)

dt = _to_datetime('07/27/2015', '06:00 AM')
print('DateTime:', dt)
# DateTime: 2015-07-27 06:00:00-04:00
```

or as [J.H. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) pointed out, you can use `pytz`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

AmericaNewYorkTz = timezone('America/New_York')

def _to_datetime(air_date, air_time):
    schedule_time = '{}:{}'.format(air_date, air_time)
    naiveDateTime = datetime.strptime(schedule_time,'%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p') 
    localizedDateTime = AmericaNewYorkTz.localize(naiveDateTime, is_dst=None)
    return localizedDateTime

dt = _to_datetime('05/27/2015', '06:00 AM')
print('DateTime:', dt)
```

Comment: [`dateutil` may fail](https://gist.github.com/zed/3838828) with timezones that observe DST. [Use `pytz` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31686932/4279).

Comment: `.replace()` should not be used either. Instead, `localize()` or `normalize()` on the timezone object should be used.

Answer (score 4):

Use `pytz` module to work with timezones in Python. To get the local timezone as `pytz` tzinfo object, you could use `tzlocal` module:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

naive = _to_datetime('07/27/2015', '06:00 AM')
aware = get_localzone().localize(naive, is_dst=None)
print(aware.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S %z'))
# -> 20150727060000 -0400
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the time zone to the parsed string with `%z`. This will give it a [`tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) attribute:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def _to_datetime(air_date, air_time):
    schedule_time = '{}:{}'.format(air_date, air_time)
    return datetime.strptime(schedule_time + ' -0400', '%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p %z')
```

Example:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('03/19/2015:03:00 PM -0400','%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p %z')
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 19, 15, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000)))
```